# Storage event Listener not working properly in Incognito or private Window

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, local-storage, microsoft-edge, addeventlistener

In normal browsers the Storage event Listener working and triggering properly

Event listener code is given below

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
      console.log("storage event occured here");
},false);
```

Storage change by using

```
 localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout'+Math.random());
```

When any changes made in local storage its trigger other browser tab storage event properly. But when  I tried same code in Incognito or Private window its working propely in `chrome` and `mozilla` browsers but not in `Edge` and `Internet Explorer` browsers

But in case Of `IE`, `Edge`  and `Brave` browser private windows this event is not triggered in my website. In other browsers its working as per expected.
Is there any way to make it work in the incognito window of `IE` and `Edge`  browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage event occurs when there is a change in the window's change area.

Note: The storage event is only triggered when a window **other than itself** makes the changes.

You could check the following sample code:

```
<button onclick="changeValue()">Change a Storage Item</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("storage", function myFunction(event) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "A change was made in the storage area";
        console.log("storage event occured here");
    }, false);

    function changeValue() {
        var x = window.open("popuppage.html", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
        x.localStorage.setItem("mytime", Date.now());
        x.close();
    }
</script>
```

When open a new window and change the local storage, it will trigger the storage event. The above code works well on my side (using IE 11 and MS Edge 44 version).

More detail about storage event, please check [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_storage_url.asp).

Comment: My issue is that event listener not triggered in  Incognito or Private window(IE and Edge) , normal way its working fine. I am using the storage change code also.

Comment: The storage event will be triggered in InPrivate IE browser (version: 11.116.18362.0), the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8iS.gif). You could try to update the IE browser version. But, this event not working in InPrivate Edge browser, it seems that this is a [public issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13356574/).

Comment: My current version is 11.523.17134

Comment: Try to create a new application using my code and test it on your side using IE 11.523.17134 version. If still not working, perhaps the issue is related to the IE browser setting, try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings). Besides, you could also try to upgrade the IE browser version.

Comment: If still not working, please try to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error?